# How can I format a cell to not wrap in a themed table with the Antonelli/Bartik theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to limit the text in a cell so it truncates whatever would be wrap to the next line. However, I want there to be a minimum width, so if a user is viewing the table on a phone oriented vertically it won't just show 1 or 2 characters because of the narrow width.

Comment: I must say I'm inclined to call "Off topic" on this one. What you need is CSS or Javascript. If you already had either of those any wanted to know how to best integrate them, then the question would have been great. Now though, I don't feel it's on the right site.

Comment: You need to go and find out how to do this in HTML/CSS/JS first; the question has nothing to do with Drupal at this point. Once you've solved that problem, if you're struggling to implement it in a particular theme then you might get away with asking on here, although my instinct is it would be too localised

Comment: I'm still not quite sure on what boundaries/limitations drupal has. For the most part I feel like I've written little php... a lot of things have functions. I wasn't sure if I was missing something with themes and thought maybe drupal had a function for declaring css. 

So yeah I'll just go about this the old fashioned way. I suppose a better questions would have been: "Is there a way to set overflow & cell width without using javascript or css"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way would be setting the min-width in the css to some value.
this would ensure no matter what device it is being viewed it will set this minimum width.
google up for sum css trick.